# How do I use resample python get the frequency-time every 1min and aggregate with mean

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the frequency-time every 1min and aggregate with mean as the excel pic attached, tried using python resample for 1 min mean but can't get the same data.

my code"

```
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df.set_index("time",inplace=True)

x = df.between_time("19:30:43", "19:36:28" ) 
x.reset_index(inplace=True)
r = x.set_index("time").resample('1T').mean()
```

excel table:
[image]

my code output:

[image]

Comment: Please post data as copyable text and not as images.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you don't want to group by every minutes from the 1st second to the last second of the minute, but you want to group by every minutes from the 30 last seconds of the last minute to the 30 first seconds of the current minute.

To do so, you can just use `resample()` with a 60 seconds frequency instead of a 1 minute frequency (`rule='60S`), then specify the sampling starts from 30 seconds after the begining of each minutes (`base=30`). That way, you will have the expected output, however, the time indices will then be set on half of each minutes like this:

```
                      sample
time    
2020-04-24 19:29:30      0.5
2020-04-24 19:30:30      3.5
2020-04-24 19:31:30      7.5
2020-04-24 19:32:30     11.5
2020-04-24 19:33:30     15.5
2020-04-24 19:34:30     18.5
```

If you want to rather use the minute the data is centered around, you can add a 30s offset to the label (`loffset='30S'`). Here is the final result :

```
                      sample
time    
2020-04-24 19:30:00      0.5
2020-04-24 19:31:00      3.5
2020-04-24 19:32:00      7.5
2020-04-24 19:33:00     11.5
2020-04-24 19:34:00     15.5
2020-04-24 19:35:00     18.5
```

And the piece of code I used to get it:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"sample": np.arange(20)},
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(
        data=[
            "19:30:13", "19:30:28", "19:30:43", "19:30:58",
            "19:31:13", "19:31:28", "19:31:43", "19:31:58",
            "19:32:13", "19:32:28", "19:32:43", "19:32:58",
            "19:33:13", "19:33:28", "19:33:43", "19:33:58",
            "19:34:13", "19:34:28", "19:34:43", "19:34:58"
        ],
        name="time"
    )
)

data.resample('60S', base=30, loffset='30S').mean()
```

Comment: Thank Falx . so I can use group by too? – fardy013 @Falx

Comment: I said group by because `resample` can be seen as a kind of `groupby` for time series, but `resample` is effectively the best way to go here imho ;)